# Flutter application/stream+json Content-Type

Tags: json, http, flutter, dart, reactive

I'm trying to make an Http Client call in flutter with content-type:application/stream+json and accept: application/stream+json,in order to use reactive response from the backend but this is what the response looks like:

```
{"name":"bobby", "lastname": "fisher"}
{"name":"dominic", "lastname": "thiem"}
{"name":"roger", "lastname": "federer"}
{"name":"a", "lastname": "b"}
{"name":"c", "lastname": "d"}
{"name":"e", "lastname": "f"}
```

without [ ] and , so how I can iterate on it?

PD: If I send application/json works but not reactive way.

Any help?

Comment: you should paste the code that have used so far. It will help other to test/correct it

Answer (score 2):

So, there's two steps we need to take here:

1. Get a raw byte stream from the network
2. Transform that stream into a json stream

Using dio, we can get the stream like this:

```dart
final response = await dio.get<ResponseBody>(
  '/streaming/url',
  options: Options(
    responseType: ResponseType.stream,
  ),
);

// Check status code, etc...

final responseStream = response.data!.stream;
```

Once we have a stream, we'll need to decode it into text, split it by line, and parse the json. This part will be identical regardless of if you're using `dio` or not.

```dart
utf8.decoder
    .bind(responseStream)
    .transform(const LineSplitter())
    .map((line) => jsonDecode(line));
```

So, the final method might look something like this

```dart
Stream<dynamic> subscribeToStream() async* {
  final response = await dio.get<ResponseBody>(
    '/streaming/url',
    options: Options(
      responseType: ResponseType.stream,
    ),
  );

  // check status, etc

  yield* utf8.decoder
      .bind(response.data!.stream)
      .transform(const LineSplitter())
      .map((line) => jsonDecode(line));
}
```

Comment: how can i get the stream data if the JSON is currently formatted.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following your question.

Comment: nothing mate, just making sure.. every stream response is in this format? not actual JSON format with []?

Comment: This question is for newline-delimited JSON, please create a new question